# Transform dot array to associative array

Tags: arrays, string, laravel, laravel-5.5

In laravel, is there any function which with I could transform a `string` divided with dots into `associative array` ?

For example:

`user.profile.settings` into `['user' => ['profile' => 'settings']]` ?

I found the `method` `array_dot`, but it works the reversed way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reverse of `array_dot` isn't exactly what you are asking for as it still needs an associative array and returns an associative array and you have only a string.

You could make this pretty easily though I suppose.

```
function yourThing($string)
{
    $pieces = explode('.', $string);
    $value = array_pop($pieces);
    array_set($array, implode('.', $pieces), $value);
    return $array;
}
```

This assumes you are passing a string with at least one dot (at least a key [before the last dot] and a value [after the last dot]). You could expand this out to be used with an array of strings and add the proper checking easily.

```
>>> yourThing('user.profile.settings')
=> [
     "user" => [
       "profile" => "settings",
     ],
   ]
```

Answer (score 3):

No, Laravel by default only gives you [array_dot()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-dot) helper, which you can use to flat an multidimensional array into dot notation array.

**Possible solutions**

Easiest way is to use [this](https://github.com/divineomega/array_undot) little package that adds array_undot() helper to your Laravel, then like the package docs says, you could do something like this:

```
$dotNotationArray = ['products.desk.price' => 100, 
                     'products.desk.name' => 'Oak Desk',
                     'products.lamp.price' => 15,
                     'products.lamp.name' => 'Red Lamp'];

$expanded = array_undot($dotNotationArray)

/* print_r of $expanded:

[
    'products' => [
        'desk' => [
            'price' => 100,
            'name' => 'Oak Desk'
        ],
        'lamp' => [
            'price' => 15,
            'name' => 'Red Lamp'
        ]
    ]
]
*/
```

Another posible solution is to create a helper function with this code:

```
function array_undot($dottedArray) {
  $array = array();
  foreach ($dottedArray as $key => $value) {
    array_set($array, $key, $value);
  }
  return $array;
}
```

Comment: Ouh, did not expect a whole package for such thing but it looks good. Thank you :)

Comment: unfortunately they don't have an array, they have a single string that is the key and value in one

Comment: @lagbox oh, didn't noticed that, tought its a normal dotation associative array. :/

Comment: yea otherwise the reverse of `array_dot` would be great .. kinda hope that their example isn't correct, but ... :)

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has an array undot method.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
 
$array = [
    'user.name' => 'Kevin Malone',
    'user.occupation' => 'Accountant',
];
 
$array = Arr::undot($array);
 
// ['user' => ['name' => 'Kevin Malone', 'occupation' => 'Accountant']]
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-undot

Answer (score -1):

Laravel doesn't offer a function like that.